# Eclipse and IDL files in C project

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse CDT for C  programming with (MinGW) and I have to install a sdk  ON ECLIPSE "called Decklink SDK". My Problem is that the SDK is in form of IDL files so I have to compile them to get somes .h and .c files so I can use them correctly. My question is how can I compile  IDL for C in eclipse.

In visual Studio it's pretty easy, but I can't use it at work.